# SQL Server invalid column name error complaining about column long gone

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**EDIT: Please read my answer below first, before you decide to read and try to understand the text below. You may not find it's worth it when you see what was going on ;)**

I have a weird problem: SQL Server 2008 R2 keeps complaining about an invalid column that is indeed not there anymore, but I'm not using it either!

I can't update any rows in that table anymore from within my own application, where no reference to the column can be found, because I always get this error now.
I then wanted to update straight in SSMS as a test, but when I edit the rows there, I still get this error.

What happened before: I made a column called CertcUL varchar(1), and that worked. After a while it appeared I needed it to be a varchar(30), so I edited the table design and turned it into a varchar(30).

From that moment I saw that I could only update this column when I stored 1 character. When I tried to store more, I got an error warning me about string or binary truncation. So somehow, the previous varchar(1) info was still present in the DB.

When I renamed that column to CertcUL2 or Cert_cUL, the same things kept happening! So changing the column name does not change the underlying cause. Also when just trying to add some characters straight in SSMS.

When I deleted the column, and added a new one with varchar(30) straight away, and called 'test', the same problem remained! This column still only allows me to store one character! The column was the one but last column. Making it the last column does not help either. Only when creating an new column while keeping the other column, I can have columns that behave properly.

So somehow, SQL Server saves some meta data about a column, even when it has been deleted. And does not look at the name, but rather at the order in which the columns are created.

Does anyone have an idea how this can happen, and how I can fix this besides (probably) dropping and recreating the whole table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Oh my God I feel so stupid...it's a trigger that still contains this column. I just noticed it because when trying to update with an update statement. Only this way I got a proper error message, so I now know what's going on. So stupid that I didn't check the triggers! Sorry about that!

More info: I had an update trigger on this table A, that copies all current values to a history table B that contains the same columns. So I did change the length of the column CertcUL in table A, but forgot about table B. So it was very confusing to see the old column name popping up every time, and see it complianing about string truncation while my column in table A seemed just fine.

Sorry again :)